# Attribute Directive with function in Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

I have the following attribute directive

```
import { Directive,HostListener,Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: `[appConfirmaction]`
})
export class ConfirmactionDirective {
  @Input() appConfirmaction = () => {};
  @Input() confirmMessage = 'Do you want to keep going?';

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  confirmFirst() {
    const confirmed = window.confirm(this.confirmMessage);

    if(confirmed) {
      this.appConfirmaction();
    }
  }
}
```

Then I'm using the above directive attribute in a button, such as

```
<button md-icon-button [appConfirmaction]="showSimpleMessage" >
```

The code of the function of the component is:

```
showSimpleMessage(){
    alert("Hello");
  }
```

This code works perfectly.

Now, suppose that I want to add a parameter to the function showSimpleMessage, such as

```
showSimpleMessage(name:string){
    alert("Hello "+name);
  }
```

What are the changes that I have to do to the attribute directive to support the new parameter without using a new @Input for the name parameter?
Also, Is this the proper way to call a function from an attribute directive with Angular4?

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use bind

```
  <button  [appConfirmaction]="showSimpleMessage.bind(null, 'Julia')" >
       click me 
  </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't have to change much. Just put argument to your calling of `showSimpleMessage` function in directive:

```
if(confirmed) {
  this.appConfirmaction('some name');
}
```

If this doesn't work correctly you can use `call()` method on that function. This solution is if you want to call it from directive:

```
if(confirmed) {
  this.appConfirmaction.call(null, 'some name');
}
```

First argument `null` is actually context `this` that you can provide to the function.
`'some name'` is the parameter of the function.

The other solution is to use `bind()` as suggested by @Julia